# JPA query issue in one to many mapping and a where clause needed in the List(many)

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have two JPA queries, Where I bring currentInvoice and historical invoices. I cannot add the filter in @Entity object and I cannot write a native query. I just put two sample tables, in reality its lots of tables joined, so native query is not an option.  And if I add any filter to column it will affect other queries

I have a mapping like this

```java
@Entity
@Table("Invocie")
Class Invoice {

int invoice_id;

@OneToMany
@JoinCoulmn(name= invoce_id)
List<Order> orders;

}
```

```java
@Entity
@Table("Order")
Class Order {

int orderID;

int invoice_id;

}

public Class ReadInvoiceRepository extends JPARepository<Invoice, Long> {

//currentinvoice query

@Query(from Invoice inv where inv.invoice_id = :invoideId and inv.orders > 0)
Invoice findByInvoiceID(int invoideId)

//historicalinvoices query

@Query(from Invoice inv where inv.invoice_id != :invoideId and inv.claim = claim and inv.order > 0)
List<Invoice> hisoricalinvocie(int invoideId,int claim)

}
```

I want to bring in currentInvoice all the orders where order_status = 0. And I want to keep orders's size is not zero. But historical query will remain same

How can I rewrite the query where  inv.orders > 0 and (inv.order.order_status = 0). The orders is a list not an object